# What does "all_df[col].str.split(";", 2).str" output?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to split a column which is shaped like: "StringA;StringB;StringC" with ";". I originally tried:

```
df[col_a], df[col_b], df[col_c] = df[col].str.split(",", 2)
```

But realize that there may not always be 3 strings, there are a lot of rows in the shape of "StringA;StringB". I found a solution online as following:

```
df[col_a], df[col_b], df[col_c] = df[col].str.split(",", 2).str
```

And this line of code works just fine. It just gives col_c the value of  NaN. I'm a little confounded as in how does adding 'str' works.

Appreciate any help!

Comment: Can you add the data sample.

Comment: str.split("sperator",max) if you used max 2 then this will split data untill two occurences of seprator found and also add remaining string in the last in a list

Answer (score 0):

`.str` is an *accessor*.

Basically, what it does is allow you to treat a `Series` of objects as specifically a `Series` of iterables (in this case, lists).

After applying `split`, each element in `df[col` now contains a list. You can do, for example, `df[col].str.split(',').str[0]`, and it will give you the first element in each list in `df[col]`.

By assigning the result of `.str` to the individual `Series`, you are performing a vectorised form of `tuple` unpacking, like `a, b, c = (1, 2, 3)`, but for *every element of the* `Series`.

Example:

```
>>> data = [['first;second;third'], ['first;second'], ['second;third;fourth'], ['fourth']]
>>> 
>>> series = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['string'])['string']
>>> split = series.str.split(';')
>>> split
0     [first, second, third]
1            [first, second]
2    [second, third, fourth]
3                   [fourth]
Name: string, dtype: object

>>> split.str[0]
0     first
1     first
2    second
3    fourth
Name: string, dtype: object
```

See also my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54553185/manipulating-a-pandas-dataframe-column-containing-a-list/54553311#54553311).